# Android vitamio library disable log

Tags: android, logging, vitamio

I am using vitamio library on my project and i dont want to display this log line. Is there any way to disable this log?

> 05-28 18:32:15.847:I/Vitamio[4.2.6]Player :OPEN FILE http:/.../master.m3u8